# Nodejs stores Date value one hour earlier in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I’m trying to save a Date value from `nodejs` in my `mongodb`, but the saved value is one day earlier.  More exactly its one hour.

If I use `console.log(new Date(this.year, this.month, this.day));` in `nodejs` I get:

> Tue Mar 19 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

but in mongodb I have following record:

> 2013-03-18 23:00:00 +0000

the record is one hour earlier.

But why? Have I to set the timezone in mongodb? I'm using Os X with:

> Time Zone: Europe/Berlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the timezone problem, just add `process.env.TZ = 'UTC'` in the `"main"`.

Comment: What do you mean by this? What is main here?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB stores time in UTC only. It is left to the application to do timezone conversions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not one hour earlier — it's stored in mongodb using timezone +00:00 instead of +01:00.

00:00 by +01:00 === 23:00 by +00:00

Comment: Thanks, how could I changed the timezone from mongodb?